# Atmosphere "async-supported should set to true" error with Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, apache2, tomcat7, atmosphere

In my primefaces based application, I'm using atmosphere framework to push data from server to client. I'm deploying app to tomcat 7.0.54. Everything seems fine if I access application via ip and port. Doesn't matter using localhost or a remote server ip, it works perfectly. But when I try to reach the app via http://domainNameWithoutPort.com/appName behind Apache2, Atmosphere throws those exceptions in client side (on Chrome):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://domain.com/appName/primepush/liveStream?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.0.8&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Cache-Date=0' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 501 domain.com/appName/javax.faces.resource/push/push.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:1
Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent).
Websocket closed, wasClean: false
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) http://domain.com/appName/primepush/liveStream?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0…k=1.0.8&X-Atmosphere-Transport=long-polling&X-Cache-Date=0&_=140722464408
```

And those exception on server side:

```
org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Invalid request state. Websocket protocol not supported
org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Invalid request state. AsyncContext#startAsync not supported. Make sure async-supported is set to true in web.xml
```

and eventually not updating the client side. I defined `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in `web.xml`, but no luck.

The versions of used technologies; Primefaces version : 3.5, Atmosphere version : 2.1.5, Tomcat 7.0.54

Hope someone would know the trick,

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Comet nor WebSocket are supported when using AJP (between httpd and Tomcat). If you use mod_proxy_http Comet should work.

Comment: I'm already using mod_proxy_http, but I found that I also need to enable proxy_wstunnel mode and define proxy for ws://whatever?websocket. That seems to solve my problem, thanks anyway.

Comment: proxy_wstunnel has quite a few limitations. It won't work in all circumstances but good that it is working for you.